# Not found constructor AndroidDriver with Appium in eclipse

Tags: java, android, appium, appium-android

**Code with errors:**

```
package TestCase;

import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URI;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.remote.CapabilityType;
import org.openqa.selenium.remote.DesiredCapabilities;
import com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.host.URL;
import io.appium.java_client.AppiumDriver;
import io.appium.java_client.android.AndroidDriver;
import io.appium.java_client.remote.MobileCapabilityType;
import io.appium.java_client.remote.MobilePlatform;

public class TestWebBrowser {
    //AppiumDriver driver = new IOSDriver();
    public static AndroidDriver driver;

    public static void main(String[] args) throws MalformedURLException {           
        DesiredCapabilities capabilities = new DesiredCapabilities();   
        driver = new AndroidDriver(new URL("http://127.0.0.1:4723/wd/hub"), capabilities);  
    }
}
```

The message error is:

> - The constructor URL(string) is undefined
> - The constructor AndroidDriver(URL, DesiredCapabilities) is undefined
> - AndroidDriver is a raw type

I have tried with different versions of java-client and still the problem persists

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use an existen constructor like this:

https://appium.github.io/java-client/io/appium/java_client/android/AndroidDriver.html

You need use `java.net.URL` and not `com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.host.URL`

Answer (score 0):

@Lorena, hi.
1. Firstly, could You please double check the imports ? Sharing code snippet below with correct ones

```
package tests.web;

import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;
import io.appium.java_client.android.AndroidDriver;
import io.appium.java_client.remote.MobileBrowserType;
import org.junit.After;
import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.remote.DesiredCapabilities;
public class AndroidWebTest {
   private static final String ACCESS_KEY = System.getenv(“SEETEST_IO_ACCESS_KEY”);
   private static final String CLOUD_URL = “https://cloud.seetest.io:443/wd/hub”;
   private static final String TITLE = “Testing Website on Android Chrome with Java”;
   private AndroidDriver driver = null;

   @Before
   public void setUp() throws MalformedURLException {
       DesiredCapabilities dc = new DesiredCapabilities();
       dc.setCapability(“testName”, TITLE);
       dc.setCapability(“accessKey”, ACCESS_KEY);
       dc.setBrowserName(MobileBrowserType.CHROME);
       driver = new AndroidDriver(new URL(CLOUD_URL), dc);
   }

   @Test
   public void testAppiumOnChrome() {
       driver.get(“https://amazon.com”);
       System.out.println(driver.getTitle());
       if (driver.getCapabilities().getCapability(“device.category”).equals(“TABLET”)) {
           driver.findElement(By.xpath(“//*[@name=’field-keywords’]”)).sendKeys(“iPhone”);
           driver.findElement(By.xpath(“//*[@text=’Go’]”)).click();
       } else {
           driver.findElement(By.xpath(“//*[@name=’k’]”)).sendKeys(“iPhone”);
           driver.findElement(By.xpath(“//*[@value=’Go’]”)).click();
       }
   }

   @After
   public void tearDown() {
       if (driver != null) {
           driver.quit();
       }
   }
}
```

Please see the [Comparing and combining web and mobile test automation drivers](https://experitest.com/selenium-testing/web_and_mobile_test_automation_drivers/) article for more details.

2. If You project is maven-based, could You please also  double check the dependencies? 
   For example, please see latest appium updates [here](https://discuss.appium.io/t/java-client-5-0-2-released/18439)
   [image]

Appropriate maven repo to check for (latest) java client: 
https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.appium/java-client

Answer (score 0):

The constructor `AndroidDriver(URL, DesiredCapabilities)` is undefined.

I solved the issue while using these versions:

java-client

```
<version>8.3.0</version>
```

TestNg

```
<version>6.14.3</version>
```